# python writing to a different text file every time

Tags: python, file, iteration

I've tried a few different methods of doing this but each one has errors or will only function in specific ways.

```
randomData = ("Some Random stuff")

with open("outputFile.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write(randomData)
    exit()
```

What i'm trying to to is write to the "outputFile.txt" file and then next output to a different file such as "outputFileTwo.txt".

Comment: don' use `exit()` - it ends your program

Comment: how do you specify the next file name?

Comment: something like `with open('file1.txt', 'wt') as file1, open('file2.txt', 'wt') as file2 : file1.write(...) file2.write(...)`

Comment: i was more trying to think of a way to do it by running the program then letting it close and then restarting the program and it not write to the same file.

Comment: then you have to write filename in other file and then read it at start to create new filename.

Comment: That is not what your question asks. There are many ways to generate file name the easiest is probably `time` i.e. something like `t,s = str(time.time()).split('.')` Then use `t` and append `.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If you need different filename at every start then you have to save in other file  (ie. `config.txt`) information about current filename. It can be number which you will use in filename (`file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, etc.).

And at start read number from `config.txt`, increase this number, use in filename, and write number again in `config.txt`.

---

Or you can use modul `datetime` to use current date and time in filename.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html

There is also module to generate temporary (random and unique) filename.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing the same data to multiple files, you can do something like this:

```
data = "some data"

files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']

for file in files:
    with open(file, "a") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment concerning a new file name for each run:

```
import time
randomData = ("Some Random stuff")
t,s = str(time.time()).split('.')
filename = t+".txt"
print ("writing to", filename)
with open(filename, "a") as file:
    file.write(randomData)
```